# Rendering each object into the space independently and rendering 2D scene over 3D scene

Tags: c++, opengl

Spoiler : this problem is long so please be patient and read until the end.

Problem number 1:
I'm making a pool project and I want to render each object separately because of the independent movement of each object.
As for right now, i'm stacking it into one buffer and rendering it in one chunk.
(side note : Each Ball object and Table object includes in it vertices and normals.)

Problem number 2:
I'm trying to render 2D bar (that represents striking power) and it won't show up. I'm calling it after im rendering the 3d scene

I've watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1mp4zflkYo) a few times and didn't understand what I did wrong.

What i'm doing right now (after stacking the objects into vertexbuffer and normalbuffer): ([original source](https://hastebin.com/agehojurox.js))

```
  do {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(programID);
    glUniform3f(LightID, 0, 6, 4);
    computeMatricesFromInputs();
    ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
    ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    MVP = ProjectionMatrix * viewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &viewMatrix[0][0]);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        2,                                // attribute
        3,                                // size
        GL_FLOAT,                         // type
        GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
        0,                                // stride
        (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
    DrawHUD();
    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
```

What I want it to be:

```
do{
        for (int i = 0;  i < BALL_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        balls[i].draw();
    }

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
```

what should `draw` contain and how do I make it work?

Comment: Did you [`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glEnable.xml) beforehand? I'm not sure if it's enabled by default but if not - your rendering is stacked according to draw order. Thinking twice... For rendering of HUD, it even might be better to `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

Comment: I did enable depth test but, when I'm entering the HUD function i'm disabling it and when i'm existing the function, i'm enabling it back again.

Answer (score 1):

Your top-level loop should:

- Clear the color and depth buffers with `glClear`
- Set scene-wide uniforms such as the light ID, projection and view matrix
- Render each ball separately: (ie the `Ball::draw` method)

  - Set the model matrix uniform to rotate and/or reposition the ball in world space. This might need recomputing the `MVP` uniform, depending on your shader code
  - (optionally) Identify the ball somehow (different color via uniform or bind a different texture)
  - Render the shared ball mesh (optionally bind the VAO for balls and then call `glDrawArrays`)
- Render the HUD
- Swap the buffer

All the setup code (loading meshes, creating array buffers and the VAO, setting up the uniform-attribute bindings) should be done up front.

Comment: The top-level loop you're talking about is my do-while loop.
I'm clearing it with glClear as you can see.
I have array that contains Ball objects and Table object.
Each ball object contains vertices, uvs(although i'm not coloring any object) and normals.
Table contains the same.

Comment: Yes. Currently it is a mix of setup code and actual drawing code. Bullet 3 describes which drawing code should go into the drawing function for balls.

Comment: Who or what is Bullet 3?

Comment: The third item in the list in my answer.

Comment: I've tried to do it didn't work...
Can you tell me how to do it?
And there is no problem with the HUD code but it doesn't work, could you explain why?

Comment: You will need to show or link to full code we can compile and run before we can help you debug.

Comment: That would be a LOT of code, can I somehow transfer it to you ?

Comment: Of course you should first make an effort to cut out irrelevant parts and produce something we can compile and run, a minimally complete verifiable example. Once you've done that, post a new question about the HUD issue.